# Free groups and their commutator subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I was trying to understand the example 3 of [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1944-50-04/S0002-9904-1944-08134-2/S0002-9904-1944-08134-2.pdf) paper of Baer.

Take a free group $F$ of rank 2. Take the commutator group $F'$ (this is a free group having infinite countable rank). Then say $N$ the commutator $[F, F'']$.

My question is the following (pag. 273 of the paper): how can we say that $F''/N$ is a free abelian group?

Of course it is a quotient of a free abelian group but I do not understand why it is free...

I know that I can work out the example also without know this fact, I just want to know how he says that; any hints?

Comment: Hint: Suppose it was not free abelian. Where did the torsion come from?

Comment: The torsion subgroup of $F''/N$ is the subgroup generated by elements $cN$ such that $c^m\in N$. So we have to show that if $c\in F''$ and $c^n\in N$, then $c\in N$. I'm having some troubles doing this; I'm working on the lenght of the words in $F''$. Is there any easy way to show that the torsion is 1?

Comment: In retrospect, I think this question is harder than I first thought. For a proof of your result (in a more general setting), check out [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.1722) of Ric Wade. It includes the original references. If this doesn't help, I'll give it some proper thought tomorrow (I am currently being anti-social and sitting on my laptop in my in-laws living room, which isn't very conducive to good thinking...).

Comment: Even if you could prove it torsion-free, that would not by itself prove it to be free abelian.

Comment: @user1729 - Thanks for the paper (also if I'm not really used to some of the methods in it xD; which is it the theorem that generalise my question? Do you perhaps mean the generalisation of the "Magnus" result on the terms of the lower central series? I have already tried that way by Magnus' book and the result is the same...). DerekHolt - It's true; there must be some "easier" path.

Comment: The final theorem, Theorem 6.4., is the theorem you are after. When you say "Magnus' book", do you mean Magnus, Karrass and Solitar? I have always found it an effort to read, while I find Ric Wade's work quite readable.

Comment: Yes, I precisely mean the Magnus, Karrass and Solitar. Theorem 6.4 does not only state that the "jump" in the lower central series are free-abelian? Here we deal with $F''$ over $[F,F'']$. How can we deduce this?